# Add same plugin to all public methods of a type

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, plugin, interceptor

Is there any chance to add a plugin to all public methods of a type without writing a separate method for all of them?

I would like to use that to log method calls. The original method is always called with unmodified parameters.

As it is intended for development/debugging, any dirty hack is appreciated.

Comment: if it's for a controller, you might use `preDispatch`, if it's something else, I don't think so, but I will look further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dirty hack I came up with: The generated interceptor classes contain all methods of the original class, if there are plugins or not. In every method, `PluginList::getNext()` is called to get the first plugin.

Unfortunately I cannot create a plugin for the plugin list itself because it will run into infinite recursion during initialization.

But with a one line edit in the generated interceptor file, I could replace the PluginList. This is added at the end of the constructor:

```
$this->pluginList = new PluginListDecorator($this->pluginList, $this->_logger);
```

**Note:** If you change generated files, be prepared to loose the changes any time! This is just a temporary addition!

And the decorator class looks as follows:

```
class PluginListDecorator implements PluginListInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PluginListInterface
     */
    private $pluginList;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(PluginListInterface $pluginList, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->pluginList = $pluginList;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function getNext($type, $method, $code = null)
    {
        $callee = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2)[1];
        if ($callee['class'] == Interceptor::class) {
            $this->logger->info('METHOD CALLED: ' . $method);
        }
        return $this->pluginList->getNext($type, $method, $code);
    }

    public function getPlugin($type, $code)
    {
        return $this->pluginList->getPlugin($type, $code);
    }
}
```

If `getNext()` is called from the interceptor itself, I do my logging, then pass the call along to the original PluginList.

Comment: ha. good catch. I can add something else, since this is temporary. The interceptor is generated only if it does not exist. So how about generating it once, then copy it from `var/generation` to your module, keeping the correct file path and doing your modifications there. this way you can safely delete `var/generation` when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works, but it's an idea.
The `Interceptor` class is generated containing all the original class public methods and all interceptor methods look like this:

```
public function doSomething(parameters list here)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'doSomething');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::doSomething($object);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('doSomething', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}
```

where `$this->subjectType` is the name of the original class and `$this->pluginList` is an implementation of `Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListInterface` (most probably `Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList`).
Now you can try something sneaky.
(Here is where my idea may fail.)
Since `$this->pluginList->getNext()` is a public method, it can be pluginized.
So create a (before or around) plugin for `getNext` and if the value of the first parameter of `getNext` (second parameter in your plugin) is your intended class name, then do your logging.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it failed indeed, looks like I am running into infinite recursion

Comment: aha...but something works. Maybe you can stop the recursion somehow. Or you can just ignore my answer and start from scratch. :)

Comment: That seemed too complicated. I started from scratch, but using `getNext()` was a good approach, thanks and upvote for that!